# Activar register_globals en PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Tengo que realizar un pequeño estudio de seguridad y comportamiento con PHP y he observado que `register_globals` como variable de `php.ini` ha dado bastantes problemas de seguridad. Quería por mi propio interés comprobar cómo se comportaba un RFI (Remote File Inclusion), pero estando `register_globals = Off` no puedo observarlo.

Uso Apache, con el Panel de control de XAMPP, y cada vez que edito `php.ini` para fijar la variable en "On" y reinicio el servidor, éste me tira con un error y me dice que Apache dejó de funcionar.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar `register_globals` a "On" y a qué se debe ese error? Puedo detallar más información si se precisa. ¡Gracias!

Comment: que versión de php y apache estas usando ? **Esta característica ha sido declarada OBSOLETA desde PHP 5.3.0 y ELIMINADA a partir de PHP 5.4.0.**

Comment: Es importante dar la versión de PHP y Apache, adicionalmente le recomiendo leer lo que dice el sitio oficial de PHP sobre register_globals http://php.net/manual/es/security.globals.php